# Matching lines containing Unicode line break chars with a dot pattern in Notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using the following Regex to search for a string in each line of a document. Every line is encapsulated with `þ`.

```
^þ.*(SEARCHSTRING).*þ$
```

But I came across a discrepancy in my count. Running the regex over the below two example lines of data will only get one hit when I'd like to capture both. This is because of the [Line Separator Character](https://www.charbase.com/2028-unicode-line-separator). My regex believes this to be a new line when in fact it is simply a new line indicator. Is there any way around this?

```
þ SEARCHSTRINGþ
þ#SEARCHSTRINGþ
```

Comment: What is the regex library? Programming language? I understand `$` does not match before `\u2028` in your case. You need to make it Unicode aware. In most cases, it is either default (Python 3, .NET) or is enabled with some modifier (Java `(?U)`, Python 2 `(?u)`, PHP `/u`)....

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm this is in Notepad++ which (according to a quick google) is using boost regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, `.` matches any char that is not a Unicode line break char.

[image]

If you need to match a *line* that is a chunk of chars other than LF and CR, use

```
^þ[^\r\n]*(SEARCHSTRING)[^\r\n]*þ$
```

[image]